# max(count ) from 2 tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

Finding the city in which the most orders were sent leads to the assignment of the city and the number of orders (the named amount column). I have 2 tables the named Customers and Orders

```
SELECT Customers.City,count( Orders.OrderID) as amount  
FROM voodoo.Customers
inner join voodoo.Orders on Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
group by  Customers.City
having amount >= all(select count(Orders.OrderID) 
from  voodoo.Customers
inner join voodoo.Orders on Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID 
group by Customers.City);
```

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oajb7.png)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: what happens if there are two cities with the highest number

Comment: +--------+--------+
| City   | Amount |
+--------+--------+
| Graz   |     10 |
+--------+--------+

Comment: Like this result .

Comment: one city with the most orders

Comment: @RomanFedorchuk sometimes there could be 2 or 3 or more cities with the most orders so you must define which city or cities

Comment: I solved this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery as you can just order by amount (descending) and limit the result to 1:

```
SELECT Customers.City, count(Orders.OrderID) as amount  
  FROM voodoo.Customers INNER JOIN voodoo.Orders 
    ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY Orders.OrderID
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT: as Thorsten Kettner pointed out, I made a copy & paste error; the correct version would `GROUP BY Customers.City`.

Comment: It would be easy. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yep. The only problem is when there are two or more cities with the top amount of orders. In that case `LIMIT 1` picks one of those cities arbitrarily.

Comment: Yes, if order is important, one could e.g. additionally order by Customers.City.

Comment: Which would still return only one city instead of all top cities. This may be desired, but usually it is not.

Comment: As Roman Fedorchuk clarified in the comments, he really wants just a single result. I upvoted your solution because I think, it's much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the order count per city, not per order. So, don't group by order, but by city. For the ranking of the cities you can use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

```
SELECT city, amount
FROM
(
  SELECT
    c.city,
    COUNT(o.orderid) AS amount,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(o.orderid) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM voodoo.customers c
  INNER JOIN voodoo.orders o ON o.customerid = c.customerid
  group by c.city
) counted_and_ranked
WHERE rnk = 1;
```